# IIS 7.5 - why my config file is not picked up

Tags: iis-7.5

I am having Windows 7 and IIS 7.5 on my machine.

For my application, I have my config files `xxx.config` and `xxx.db.config`
located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`

with both being referenced in `machine.config` as -

```
<appSettings file="xxx.config"/>
  <connectionStrings configSource="xxx.db.config"/>
```

There are around 10 connection strings in xxx.db.config file. However, when I try to access connection string using following C# code-

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringXXX"]
```

No connection string except the default-

```
.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

are being returned :-(

P.S. when working with above setting in another Windows 2003 machine with IIS 6, I am able to see all the connection strings available in xxx.db.config

Can anyone please guide what could be the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your site's application pool settings to make sure it's configured for .NET Framework 2.0 and 64 bit mode:

[image]

Comment: yes, I reconfirmed, both these settings are same.