# IIS not picking up inherited connection strings

Tags: iis, connection-strings

So this question is a duplicate of: [IIS 7.5 - why my config file is not picked up](https://serverfault.com/questions/353251/iis-7-5-why-my-config-file-is-not-picked-up) but there was no answer on there and [IIS Connection String not being inherited](https://serverfault.com/questions/386118/iis-connection-string-not-being-inherited) had an answer but the accepted answer didn't help me.

We have junction pointers set up for both 32- and 64-bit configs under each .NET framework version under C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net to point to a folder we have setup, C:\TSNetConfig.

So we have:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\TSNetConfig
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\TSNetConfig
```

Where `TSNetConfig` is the the junction pointer. Under the `TSNetConfig` folder we have a `SystemWideConnectionStrings.xml` file which contains, as you may guess, all of our connection strings for all of our applications.

We edit the machine.config file underneath each config folder to have this in it:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="TSNetConfig\SystemWideConnectionStrings.xml" />
```

For some reason though, when we look under Connection Strings for each site in IIS, it only has one default string that is published when the application is deployed. It doesn't pick up any of the others. We use this setup on several other IIS servers, and they populate just fine; however none of the applications on this server will pick them up.

Some things I've already checked:

- Made sure app pools are set up to run on proper framework version
- Made sure app pool defaults to running on the proper framework version as suggested in the second question I linked

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings have been picked up from the following locations it seems.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
and 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config